# Solving equation in Matlab

Tags: exponential-function, matlab

I want to solve this equation for several values of `y`

```
y=4 exp(0,034x)

y= [60 14 63 34 21 12 11];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not mainly a site for programming specific help, so don't be surprised if people sometimes vote down questions that are too specific about computer language. You can use the **fsolve** command and an anonymous function

```
f = @(x)[60 14 63 34 21 12 11]' - 4*exp(0.034.*x);
x_solution = fsolve(f,rand(1,7)');
```

Comment: Or she can simply use the natural logarithm function, which would result in much faster code. I am horrified to see people like the OP who become programmers without mastering high-school mathematics.

Comment: If she is learning a new computer language maybe she is trying functions she can find the solution to on her own to see if she is using the language right.

Comment: @Alex. M , I had more or less the same opinion some years ago, but I am now convinced, as mathreader is that even good students, faced to scientific software are so obsessed by the programming aspects that they appear to loose their previous knowledge ; it is only in a second step, sometimes a year (or two...) later, that they have gained enough confidence in themselves that they can 'merge' their computer science and mathematics abilities

Comment: @JeanMarie That can sometimes be the case but that is not what I meant. By learning to use a numerical software one usually intends (at one point or another) to use it for solving things which are difficult or impossible to solve analytically or algebraically. Then it can be good to start out making sure one can use it correctly by using it on stuff that can be verified easily by analytic and algebraic methods.

Comment: @mathreader I agree